ggplot's geom_smooth fails with formula y~x
ggplot2: When I change the formula in geom_smooth from y~x to x~y, I get an error message.
Example:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

N <- 10000
mu = 175.9   #cm -- adult male height, England
sigma = 6.35 #cm -- adult male height, England
rho <- 0.5   # Father-son correlation

pts <- mvrnorm(n = N, mu = c(mu, mu), Sigma = sigma ^ 2 * matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), ncol = 2))
df <- tibble(father = pts[,1], son = pts[,2])

ggplot(df, aes(x=father, y=son)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  xlim(150, 202) + 
  ylim(150, 202) + 
  labs(title = "Adult height of fathers and sons, England", x = "X = Father height (cm)", y = "Y = Son height (cm)") +
  geom_point(shape = '.', alpha = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) +  
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, linewidth=.3, colour = 'blue', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 191, y = 186, angle = 26, colour = 'blue', label = 'Regression line of Y on X') +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = x~y, linewidth=.3, colour = 'red', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 186, y = 191, angle = 90 - 26, colour = 'red', label = 'Regression line of X on Y')

Output:


Keep the formula as y~x and set orientation = "y" in geom_smooth() for the regression line of X on Y.

@Seth, please post as answer ...

I believe the issue is that for a given data set, the regression of y ~ x,  x ~ y are the same line (so you're only going to see the one on top of the other).
See below, where I broke your plot into 2 plots, while switching the son to be x on the second plot.
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

N <- 10000
mu = 175.9   #cm -- adult male height, England
sigma = 6.35 #cm -- adult male height, England
rho <- 0.5   # Father-son correlation

pts <- mvrnorm(n = N, mu = c(mu, mu), Sigma = sigma ^ 2 * matrix(c(1, rho, rho, 1), ncol = 2))
df <- tibble(father = pts[,1], son = pts[,2])

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=father, y=son)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  xlim(150, 202) + 
  ylim(150, 202) + 
  labs(title = "Adult height of fathers and sons, England", x = "X = Father height (cm)", y = "Y = Son height (cm)") +
  geom_point(shape = '.', alpha = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) +  
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, linewidth=.3, colour = 'blue', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 191, y = 186, angle = 26, colour = 'blue', label = 'Regression line of Y on X')

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=son, y=father)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  xlim(150, 202) + 
  ylim(150, 202) + 
  labs(title = "Adult height of sons and fathers, England", x = "X = Sons height (cm)", y = "Y = Father's height (cm)") +
  geom_point(shape = '.', alpha = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x, linewidth=.3, colour = 'red', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 186, y = 191, angle = 26, colour = 'red', label = 'Regression line of Y on X')

p1
p2

Plot 1: x = fathers, y = sons:

Plot 2: x = sons, y = fathers:


Providing the same formula = y~x, the orientation of the second regression line can be switched to the y-axis.
ggplot(df, aes(x=father, y=son)) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + 
  xlim(150, 202) + 
  ylim(150, 202) + 
  labs(title = "Adult height of fathers and sons, England", x = "X = Father height (cm)", y = "Y = Son height (cm)") +
  geom_point(shape = '.', alpha = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) +  
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, linewidth=.3, colour = 'blue', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 191, y = 186, angle = 26, colour = 'blue', label = 'Regression line of Y on X') +
  # Second linear regression with the axis of orientation switched.
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~x, orientation = "y", linewidth=.3, colour = 'red', na.rm = TRUE) + 
  annotate("text", x = 186, y = 191, angle = 90 - 26, colour = 'red', label = 'Regression line of X on Y')


